# ESTA application changed status from authorized to pending

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, application-status

My ESTA application got approved 30 minutes after submitting, and I have printed out the "Authorization Approved" document with all the details. Now, almost 48 hours later, I have received an email that my application's status has changed - and it has changed to "Authorization Pending"!

The "Payment Summary" section does not show payments details anymore, but I'm almost sure it did the first time I logged in to check the application status after receiving the latest email:

[image: payment summary showing empty details]

I paid the fee with PayPal and cannot see anything wrong with the payment on PayPal's site. The header on the top says that payment has been submitted, so this might be a red herring:

[image: application status headers saying "authorization pending" and "payment submitted"]

I cannot find any account of this happening to someone else, and I'm not sure what to do. My flight is in around 30 hours from now.

Comment: What site are you using?

Comment: @phoog https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/

Comment: Just wondering… is there any chance you may have made two applications, and while one was approved the other wasn’t (due to the duplication, probably)?

Comment: @jcaron I had only one application, the application number is the same now as it was at the time it got approved

Comment: If you are still around, what happened next? Did the status change back?